# Imagemapster is not working on hovers over hotspots in IE9 browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap, imagemapster

I am using the Imagemapster JavaScript library to generate data when the mouse hovers over image hotspots.

The application is working fine (when hovering over hotspots some data shows up) in all browsers except IE9. I cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can verify in your code. When you use "coords" field of "area" tag. IE doesn't support "new line" among coords while other browsers support.

e.g.
IE feels good like this (all in the same line):

```
<area shape="poly" href="#" alt="red hotspot" coords="823,144,822,143,822,142,822,140" />
```

but something as below, IE will fail to recgenize the format:

```
    <area shape="poly" href="#" alt="red hotspot" coords="823,144,822,[New Line]
143,822,142,822,140" />
```